# Python, Selenium: Pull Price from String

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was able to cobble together a program that opens a web page, logs in, and searches for a particular part using Selenium/Python.

My end goal is to cycle through a series of Part Numbers, and Return the Price, printing to a list.

Currently, I am trying to pull price data for a part, but unsure how. 
A bunch of parts is returned upon my search within this site. No part has an attribute associated with a price. I am having trouble on how to isolate the part I need.

I made a UN/Password specificly to ask questions. This non-private UN/PW is:

```
userName = "FirstName.SurName321123@gmail.com"
password = "PasswordForThis123"
```

The site is [Tessco.com](https://tessco.com)

I am assuming first challenge is to locate the part I need from the list returned. I know I can locate an item with the following syntax:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "someID").get_attribute("attribute")
```

But if there is no attribute to the item, how can I extract its data? Some method of extracting strings?

I was thinking of calling an `IF` function stating if some "MFG PART #:" == "string in question", in this case HL4RP-50, then print the price.

If I am able to isolate the part in question, how can I extract the price for it?

The Tessco site's HTML Code is:

```html
    <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2 col-md-2 productImage">
                                                    <a href="/product/1-2-plenum-air-cable-off-white-574840" class="CoveoResultLink" onclick="ClickToProductDetailGA({name: &quot;1/2\&quot; Plenum Air Cable, Off White&quot;, sku: 574840, price: &quot;$1.89&quot;, brand: &quot;CommScope&quot;, category: &quot;Cable Products| Coaxial Cable, Connectors &amp; Jumpers| Air Coaxial Cable| 1/2\&quot; Air Cable&quot;, position: 0, pageType: &quot;Search Page&quot;, url: &quot;/product/574840&quot; });" tabindex="0">
                                                        <img src="https://avalanche.tessco.com/productimages/250x250/1462639.jpg" alt="CommScope">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a class="hidden-xs" href="/search#f:manufacturerName=[CommScope]">
                                                        CommScope
                                                    </a>

                                                    <span class="badge blueBadge">GSA</span>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-7 visible-xs detailMobile">
                                                    <a href="/product/1-2-plenum-air-cable-off-white-574840" class="productName CoveoResultLink" onclick="ClickToProductDetailGA({name: &quot;1/2\&quot; Plenum Air Cable, Off White&quot;, sku: 574840, price: &quot;$1.89&quot;, brand: &quot;CommScope&quot;, category: &quot;Cable Products| Coaxial Cable, Connectors &amp; Jumpers| Air Coaxial Cable| 1/2\&quot; Air Cable&quot;, position: 0, pageType: &quot;Search Page&quot;, url: &quot;/product/574840&quot; });" tabindex="0">1/2" Plenum Air Cable, Off White</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7 detail">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <a href="/product/1-2-plenum-air-cable-off-white-574840" class="productName CoveoResultLink hidden-xs" onclick="ClickToProductDetailGA({name: &quot;1/2\&quot; Plenum Air Cable, Off White&quot;, sku: 574840, price: &quot;$1.89&quot;, brand: &quot;CommScope&quot;, category: &quot;Cable Products| Coaxial Cable, Connectors &amp; Jumpers| Air Coaxial Cable| 1/2\&quot; Air Cable&quot;, position: 0, pageType: &quot;Search Page&quot;, url: &quot;/product/574840&quot; });" tabindex="0">1/2" Plenum Air Cable, Off White</a>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                                <ul class="unlisted info">
                                                                    <li><span>TESSCO SKU:</span> 574840</li>
                                                                    <li><span>QTY:</span> 1 FOOT</li>
                                                                    <li><span>UPC:</span> 888063388620</li>
                                                                    <li><span>MFG PART #:</span> HL4RPV-50</li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p class="more">ANDREW 1/2" Plenum Air 50 ohm cable. HL4RPV-50. Uses LDF4 connectors. Off…</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 purchase">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <add-product-to-cart params="
                                                                             sku: 574840,
                                                                             price: &quot;$1.89&quot;,
                                                                             listPrice: &quot;$6.37&quot;,
                                                                             canPurchase: &quot;true&quot;,
                                                                             isAuthenticated: true,
                                                                             name: &quot;1/2\&quot; Plenum Air Cable, Off White&quot;,
                                                                             brand: &quot;CommScope&quot;,
                                                                             category: &quot;Cable Products| Coaxial Cable, Connectors &amp; Jumpers| Air Coaxial Cable| 1/2\&quot; Air Cable&quot;,
                                                                             pageType: &quot;Search Page&quot;,
                                                                             brandProtectionLink:&quot;/brand-protection-program&quot;,
                                                                             viewProductPricingText: &quot;viewAccountPricingOnTCOM&quot;,
                                                                             userRoles: &quot;canBuy, authorizedBuyerOnTCOM, viewAccountAvailabilityOnTCOM, viewAccountPricingOnTCOM, viewOrderHistoryOnTCOM, overrideShiptoAddressOnTCOM&quot;,
                                                                             minQuantity:1,
                                                                             minQuantityBefore: &quot;Minimum &quot;,
                                                                             minQuantityAfter: &quot; to Order&quot;,
                                                                             isOnSale: &quot;No&quot;,
                                                                             saleClass:&quot;redBadge&quot;,
                                                                             saleText:&quot;Sale&quot;,
                                                                             isCutCable: &quot;true&quot;,
                                                                             maximumReelLength: 2000,
                                                                             isCableJumper: false,
                                                                             isPricingWrapperAlive: true,
                                                                             context: &quot;search&quot;,
                                                                             index: 0, index: 0" data-sellingrestrictioncode="N/A"><div class="price" data-bind="visible: ((canPurchase()===true) &amp;&amp; (isAuthenticated()===true)), css: {sale: isOnSale} ">
        <span data-bind="text: 'List: ' + listPrice()">List: $6.37</span>
        <span data-bind="visible: isOnSale, css:saleClass, text: saleText" class="badge large redBadge" style="display: none;">Sale</span><!--
        --><!--ko text: canViewPricing()===true ? price : listPrice-->$1.89<!--/ko-->
    </div>
```

So far, my Selenium code is:

```py
    import time
    #Need Selenium for interacting with web elements
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    #Need numpy/pandas to interact with large datasets
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    chrome_path = r"C:\Users\James\Documents\Python Scripts\jupyterNoteBooks\ScrapingData\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("https://www.tessco.com/login")

    userName = "FirstName.SurName321123@gmail.com"
    password = "PasswordForThis123"

    #Set a wait, for elements to load into the DOM
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "userID"))) 
    elem.send_keys(userName)

    elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))) 
    elem.send_keys(password)

    #Press the login button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/account-login/div/div[1]/form/div[6]/div/button").click()

    #Expand the search bar
    searchIcon = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/i"))) 
    searchIcon.click()

    searchBar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/header/div[3]/input'))) 
    searchBar.click()

    #load in manufacture part number from a collection of components, via an Excel file

    #Enter information into the search bar
    searchBar.send_keys("HL4RPV-50" + '\n')
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic that you need.

```
# wait for the products information loaded
products = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='CoveoResult']")))
# create a dictionary to store product and price
productInfo = {}
# iterate through all products in the search result and add details to dictionary
for product in products:
    # get product name
    productName = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='productName CoveoResultLink hidden-xs']").text
    # get price
    price = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='price']").text.split('\n')[1]
    # add details to dictionary
    productInfo[productName] = price
# print products information   
print(productInfo)
```

**Below is the output:**

> {'1/2" Plenum Air Cable, Off White': '$6.37', '1/2" Plenum Air Cable, Blue': '$6.37', '4.3-10 Male for 1/2" AL4RPV-50,LDF4-50A,HL4RPV-50': '$25.91', '4.3-10M RA for 1/2" AL4RPV-50, LDF4-50A, HL4RPV-50': '$51.28', '4.3-10 Male Connector for 1/2” Plenum Cables': '$34.32', '4.3-10 Female Connector for 1/2" Plenum': '$35.00', '4.3-10 R/A Male Connector for 1/2" Plenum': '$47.50', '4.3-10 Female for 1/2 in AL4RPV-50, LDF4-50A': '$25.91'}

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the logical breakdown! I am mulling over the code, and concept, now. It works perfectly.

Comment: Hope I wasn't being annoying placing in a UN/PW. The site doesn't let you see pricing without a UN/PW. I made a generic one just for the question. Regardless, thank you for your help and lesson!!

Comment: I read your update later and reverted the changes to show the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow get the path for that price, then get the outer html code, use substring on in to get the one you need, which is the value in that outer html.

```
price_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('#xpath of the price here')
price_html = price_element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
price_html = price_html[#substring here]
```

It's hard to replicate or show since the website you are trying to scrape requires log in to see the prices.

But I hope this gives you an idea. Good luck man :D.

Comment: If you need an integer or float value just use `int()` or `float()` on that `price_html`